# What is the meaning of this BASH SED command?

Tags: bash

Example of tnum ... HYH19986_T_DRIVER_BAG_PRESSURE__78ms_546ms

```
tnum=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/_.*$//'`
```

The end result is that tnum will eventually become HYH19986. I have absolutely no experience of BASH but a quick search found that SED is the stream editor and essentially a find an replace too.

Please could someone explain to me what everything means from the -e onwards? Thank you.

Comment: `s/pattern/repl/` replaces the first occurence of the pattern with the string `repl`.  `_.*$` matches a literal `_` followed by any character (`.*`) up to the end of the line `$`. So this just deletes everything from and including the first underscore to the end of the line.

Comment: It means whoever wrote this didn't know about `tnum=${1%%_*}`. This means to assign `tnum` whatever `$1` produces after removing the longest suffix starting with `_`.

Answer (score 3):

Sed is the "stream editor". It is a non-interactive text editor, that takes commands to edit text. It's most commonly used command is "s", short for "substitute". This takes two expressions and optionally some options, and replaces the first expression with the second one.

The character after the "s" is the delimiter - it separates the expressions. Typically this is "/", but if you are working e.g. with paths it might be nicer to use something different like `:` or `_` so you don't need to escape every `/`.

The `_.*$` is a regular expression. Sed matches this, and replaces it with the second expression, the bit between the second and third slash, i.e. nothing in this case.

`_` is a literal underline, `.*` is "any number of characters" and `$` is the end of the line.

After that third slash you could also give options, like "g" (I remember it as "global"), which would cause this to be run multiple times per line. That's missing, but in this case the expression matches to the end of the line anyway, so nothing would change.

So this substitutes anything after an underline with nothing, which results in trimming it.

Answer (score 1):

`s/pattern/repl/` replaces the first occurrence of the pattern with the string `repl`. `_.*$` matches a literal `_` followed by the longest string of zero or more of any character (`.*`) up to the end of the line (`$`). So this just deletes everything from and including the first underscore to the end of the line.